# Expo Go release channel different versions of app inquiry

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I working on a mobile app that utilizes locations from the api provided by Expo. I need to test different accuracies and that requires publishing different versions of the app.

I want to test accuracy: 6, accuracy: 5, accuracy: 4, accuracy: 1

So far I published a default channel with the accuracy being 6. Do I just change the code that is responsible for the accuracy, save it (not commit and push it to git, just saved it), and then publish it `expo publish --release-channel accuracy5`?

Am I missing something?

Also, how does one delete a channel published?

https://docs.expo.dev/archive/classic-updates/release-channels/?redirected DOCS I used.

I changed the code, saved it and then published it. I just want to be sure that it did indeed publish with the altered accuracy value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to test different versions of the app through Expo Go, then different release-channels (therefore QR codes / urls) may be a viable approach.

Regarding testing what you have published, one of the best ways is to utilize `expo publish:history` that would give you the history of different publishing, it can give you the channel and `publicationId` that you can then use in `expo publish:details --publish-id <THE_PUBLISH_ID>`.

Then you can either take a look at the actual published bundle under `s3Url`, or better just rely on some extra metadata that has been updated with this publish (e.g. you can change a version to smth like `1.0.0-accuracy5`). The same way you can just make some dummy visual app change to see the newer version reflected in the new channel.